# fail to pass reference (variable with ampersand) to another variable

Tags: c

I tried to assign a reference to an object to another variable

```
scene_t temp = &scene;
```

However, I got this error message

```
error: incompatible types when assigning to type 'scene_t' from type 'struct scene_t *'
```

I also tried to use a pointer

```
scene_t temp = *scene
```

And I got a different error

```
type argument of unary '*' (have 'scene_t')
```

what should I do?

Comment: In C, there are no references per se; that concept applies to C++.  There are pointers, and as the compiler says, you can't assign a pointer (`struct scene_t *`) to a structure (`scene_t`, presumably equivalent to `struct scene_t`).  The second notation tries to dereference a non-pointer; you can't do that, either.  You need just: `scent_t temp = scene;` — boring, but simple.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is unlikely to help other visitors to Stack Overflow in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the type of `scene` is `scene_t` then it should be obvious that the type of `&scene` is `scene_t*`, which is what the compiler is complaining about. If `scene_t` is a `typedef` for a `struct` or a non-array built-in type you should just write

```
scene_t temp = scene;
```

or

```
scene_t* temp = &scene;
```

depending on the semantics that you want. Probably the former.

---

If `scene_t` is actually an array type then the first option above will not work. The second one *will*, but is actually wordier than you need. It would be enough to do

```
thing_scene_t_is_an_array_of * temp = scene;
```

Either way you are just getting a new pointer to the old data, and overwriting one overwrite the other, so watch out.

---

Note that using the word "reference" in the context of the address-of operator (`&`) suggest that you are viewing this from a c++ POV. C does not have c++ style references and you should not think about `&` in that way.

Comment: thx. I don't know why, but the second one is working. However, the first one isn't working at all

Comment: If the first one is failing it is likely that `scene_t` is fundamentally an array. C does not implement array assignment (but you can fudge it by wrapping the array in a `struct`). Be aware that with the second case `*temp` is *the same memory* as `scene`, and overwriting one overwrites the other.